# Can't see Time Capsule drives when Wifi is turned off

Tags: time-machine, time-capsule

Due to the fact that Apple has dropped support for all Wifi devices I have opted to migrate my home office Wifi to a Ubiquiti AC-AP-Pro with a Ubiquiti EdgeRouter X SFP as the main firewall/router.  The setup has the EdgeRouter out front with 1 WAN (eth0), 3 LAN (eth1-eth3) and 1 future "DMZ" (eth4).  The AP-AC-Pro is hung off eth3, and I moved my primary Time Capsule to eth2 (secondary Time Capsule is plugged into one of the LAN ports of the primary Time Capsule) and turned off Wifi in settings for both the primary and secondary Time Capsules.

I thought once I neutered all the features of the Time Capsule it would simply work as a network storage drive, but what I am finding is that none of my Macs can see the Time Capsules at all.  I can't see them on in Finder, can't see them in the Airport Utility, and I definitely can't see them under the Time Machine settings.

Is what I am trying to accomplish impossible?  Does the Time Capsule not support backups over the WAN port w/ Wifi turned off?  How do I even get back to the device setup in Airport Utility to even try to reconfigure the Time Capsules?  I have googled every possible way, but I am not finding anyone trying to use the Time Capsule as just a backup device.